# Getting an error in post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I'm getting this error in a post request:

```
undefined method `headers' for HTTP:Module
```

I'm using this gem: https://github.com/httprb/http.rb

This is my action:

```
def upgrade
 require "uri"
 require "net/https"
 @tokenPagamento = params[:tokenPagamento]
 @teste = Gyoku.xml(
:integracao => {:metodo => params[:metodo], :forma_pagamento => {:cartao => {:parcelas => 1}}, :token_pagamento => params[:tokenPagamento]})
 xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(@teste,nil,'UTF-8')
 params = {'dados' => xml_doc, 'tokenPagamento' => @tokenPagamento, 'token' => '1233A569C5DD32C0F96410A6C82E04543F81369C'}
 HTTP.headers(:accept => "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8").post('https://go.gerencianet.com.br/teste/api/checkout/pagar/xml', :body => params)
end
```

the error is in the last line

Comment: add a `require "http"` maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a namespace conflict between two different HTTP modules. Create a Gemfile containing:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "http", github: "httprb/http.rb"
```

run:

```
bundle install
bundle exec irb
```

Afterwards you will be able to do

```
HTTP.headers(:accept => "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8")
```